# Is there a way I can search some info in Google from Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-search

I have a Google Sheet that contains information of companies and names, and I would like to have their job position. Is there a way I can look for it in Google without doing it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets doesn't include a built-in feature do that but Google Docs has it. From [See and use suggested content in a document](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2481802?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform=Desktop)

> Find and add suggested content to documents in Google Docs. The suggested content is related to what’s in your document. You can also search your docs and the web from within a document.

To do something similar you will have to use an add-on or Google Apps Script.